# Python - Reportlabs content placement

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm generating a table, with dynamic content. The issue that I'm facing is when I provide a co-ordinate to place my table, the table start from that co-ordinate growing upwards. It should rather grow downwards. While growing upwards, it clashes with my other page contents.

**Here is my code.**

```
table = plot_meter_table(bar_labels,bar_data)
table.wrapOn(the_canvas, width, height)
table.drawOn(the_canvas, *coord(3, 46, cm))
the_canvas.showPage()
```

How should I make my table grow upwards? Also it hampers my data as well, since last entries in the table gets cut-off. How do I make my data flowable to the nextpage.

Comment: Not really an answer, but after fighting with reportlab for about a month I came to the conclusion that to do anything particularly complicated involving tables, [wkhtml2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is much more capable.

Comment: What I read it's for HTML to PDF . Right? But I want to create a PDF with the data I have.

Comment: Yes, but there are plenty of excellent tools to create html from data and a template, e.g. [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).  If you are creating a document of any size, you will want to template it anyway rather than writing pages of code to format it.